# Sort Date for different value of particular field in Single Query

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have following content on index.

```
{ date : 2019-01-21T08:20:18.962Z , student : "A", "City": "city1" }
{ date : 2019-01-21T08:20:55.962Z , student : "A", "City": "city1" }
{ date : 2019-01-21T08:29:20.962Z , student : "B", "City": "city1" }
{ date : 2019-01-21T08:20:10.962Z , student : "A", "City": "city1" }
{ date : 2019-01-21T08:29:21.962Z , student : "B", "City": "city1" }
```

I want to get the latest date for student A and Student B in single query so that I will get following output :

```
{ date : 2019-01-21T08:20:55.962Z , student : "A", "City": "city1" }
{ date : 2019-01-21T08:29:21.962Z , student : "B", "City": "city1" }
```

I know using sorting on date desc and applying must match on student : "A" will get me latest date for student A , and like wise for student B. But I need to run two separate query for this.

Please let know if we can achieve this in single query and how .

Thanks .

I have tried sort with must match filter

Answer (score 0):

You aggregation (= groupby)on student.
You will have your documents grouped by stutengs. You just have to keep the records you want after:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html